# C# How to generate a new string based on multiple ranged index

Tags: c#, string, indexing, range, substring

Let's say I have a `string` like this one, left part is a word, right part is a collection of indices (single or range) used to reference furigana (phonetics) for kanjis in my word:

```
string myString = "子で子にならぬ時鳥,0:こ;2:こ;7-8:ほととぎす"
```

The pattern in detail:

```
word,<startIndex>(-<endIndex>):<furigana>
```

What would be the best way to achieve something like this (with a space in front of the kanji to mark which part is linked to the [furigana]):

```
子[こ]で 子[こ]にならぬ 時鳥[ほととぎす]
```

**Edit**: (thanks for your comments guys)

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = "ABCDEF,1:test;3:test2";

            //Split Kanjis / Indices
            string[] tokens = myString.Split(',');

            //Extract furigana indices
            string[] indices = tokens[1].Split(';');

            //Dictionnary to store furigana indices
            Dictionary<string, string> furiganaIndices = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //Collect
            foreach (string index in indices)
            {
                string[] splitIndex = index.Split(':');
                furiganaIndices.Add(splitIndex[0], splitIndex[1]);
            }

            //Processing
            string result = tokens[0] + ",";

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens[0].Length; i++)
            {
                string currentIndex = i.ToString();

                if (furiganaIndices.ContainsKey(currentIndex)) //add [furigana]
                {
                    string currentFurigana = furiganaIndices[currentIndex].ToString();
                    result = result + " " + tokens[0].ElementAt(i) + string.Format("[{0}]", currentFurigana);
                }
                else //nothing to add
                {
                    result = result + tokens[0].ElementAt(i);
                }
            }

            File.AppendAllText(@"D:\test.txt", result + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Result:

```
ABCDEF,A B[test]C D[test2]EF
```

I struggle to find a way to process ranged indices:

```
string myString = "ABCDEF,1:test;2-3:test2";
Result : ABCDEF,A B[test] CD[test2]EF
```

Comment: Can you create an example using just alphanumeric characters, please? Also, you should share your attempt, code you tried, etc.

Comment: A [Short, Self Contained, and Correct (compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/) would help clarify what you are trying to do immensly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have anything against manually manipulating strings per se. But given that you seem to have a regular pattern describing the inputs, it seems to me that a solution that uses regex would be more maintainable and readable. So with that in mind, here's an example program that takes that approach:

```
class Program
{
    private const string _kinvalidFormatException = "Invalid format for edit specification";

    private static readonly Regex
        regex1 = new Regex(@"(?<word>[^,]+),(?<edit>(?:\d+)(?:-(?:\d+))?:(?:[^;]+);?)+", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        regex2 = new Regex(@"(?<start>\d+)(?:-(?<end>\d+))?:(?<furigana>[^;]+);?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = "子で子にならぬ時鳥,0:こ;2:こ;7-8:ほととぎす";
        string result = EditString(myString);
    }

    private static string EditString(string myString)
    {
        Match editsMatch = regex1.Match(myString);

        if (!editsMatch.Success)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(_kinvalidFormatException);
        }

        int ichCur = 0;
        string input = editsMatch.Groups["word"].Value;
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Capture capture in editsMatch.Groups["edit"].Captures)
        {
            Match oneEditMatch = regex2.Match(capture.Value);

            if (!oneEditMatch.Success)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(_kinvalidFormatException);
            }

            int start, end;

            if (!int.TryParse(oneEditMatch.Groups["start"].Value, out start))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(_kinvalidFormatException);
            }

            Group endGroup = oneEditMatch.Groups["end"];

            if (endGroup.Success)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(endGroup.Value, out end))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(_kinvalidFormatException);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                end = start;
            }

            text.Append(input.Substring(ichCur, start - ichCur));
            if (text.Length > 0)
            {
                text.Append(' ');
            }
            ichCur = end + 1;
            text.Append(input.Substring(start, ichCur - start));
            text.Append(string.Format("[{0}]", oneEditMatch.Groups["furigana"]));
        }

        if (ichCur < input.Length)
        {
            text.Append(input.Substring(ichCur));
        }

        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This implementation assumes that the edit specifications will be listed in order and won't overlap. It makes no attempt to validate that part of the input; depending on where you are getting your input from you may want to add that. If it's valid for the specifications to be listed out of order, you can also extend the above to first store the edits in a list and sort the list by the start index before actually editing the string. (In similar fashion to the way the other proposed answer works; though, why they are using a dictionary instead of a simple list to store the individual edits, I have no idea…that seems arbitrarily complicated to me.)
- I included basic input validation, throwing exceptions where failures occur in the pattern matching. A more user-friendly implementation would add more specific information to each exception, describing what part of the input actually was invalid.
- The `Regex` class actually has a `Replace()` method, which allows for complete customization. The above could have been implemented that way, using `Replace()` and a `MatchEvaluator` to provide the replacement text, instead of just appending text to a `StringBuilder`. Which way to do it is mostly a matter of preference, though the `MatchEvaluator` might be preferred if you have a need for more flexible implementation options (i.e. if the exact format of the result can vary).
- If you do choose to use the other proposed answer, I strongly recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead of simply concatenating onto the `results` variable. For short strings it won't matter much, but you should get into the habit of *always* using `StringBuilder` when you have a loop that is incrementally adding onto a string value, because for long string the performance implications of using concatenation can be very negative.

Comment: agreed that it is a better practice to use StringBuilder for things like this (but would have a *very* small performance gain in this example), I was just trying to keep the example simpler.  If anyone wants my solution tweaked to incorporate SB, just let me know; it would only be a few lines difference.

Comment: Hello Peter ! At first I wanted to use regex but later on, I gave up after checking sample  code using japanese. In the end, it's not that complicated and I really like the concept of using `<>` to refer each part of the regex expression (what is the name of this attribute ?). It's a very interesting approach, gonna check it more today and might come back with a couple of questions if you don't mind !

Comment: I don't mind questions at all. Though, it's better to limit questions in comments to things you need to ask in order to understand an answer better (especially if those question highlight deficiencies in the answer, so that I can edit the answer and make it better). Broader questions that stray from the topic at hand are best addressed in a new Stack Overflow question. :) As for the "name of this attribute", I don't know if there's a technical term. It's just the name of the capture group. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs for details.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (and even handle ranged indices), based on the formatting of the input string you have-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class stringParser
{
    private struct IndexElements 
    {
        public int start;
        public int end;
        public string value;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {   
        //input string
        string myString = "子で子にならぬ時鳥,0:こ;2:こ;7-8:ほととぎす";
        int wordIndexSplit = myString.IndexOf(',');
        string word = myString.Substring(0,wordIndexSplit);
        string indices = myString.Substring(wordIndexSplit + 1);

        string[] eachIndex = indices.Split(';');
        Dictionary<int,IndexElements> index = new Dictionary<int,IndexElements>();
        string[] elements;
        IndexElements e;
        int dash;
        int n = 0;
        int last = -1;
        string results = "";

        foreach (string s in eachIndex)
        {
            e = new IndexElements();
            elements = s.Split(':');
            if (elements[0].Contains("-"))
            {
                dash = elements[0].IndexOf('-');
                e.start = int.Parse(elements[0].Substring(0,dash));
                e.end = int.Parse(elements[0].Substring(dash + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                e.start = int.Parse(elements[0]);
                e.end = e.start;
            }
            e.value = elements[1];

            index.Add(n,e);
            n++;
        }

        //this is the part that takes the "setup" from the parts above and forms the result string
        //loop through each of the "indices" parsed above
        for (int i = 0; i < index.Count; i++)
        {
            //if this is the first iteration through the loop, and the first "index" does not start 
            //at position 0, add the beginning characters before its start
            if (last == -1 && index[i].start > 0)
            {
                results += word.Substring(0,index[i].start);
            }
            //if this is not the first iteration through the loop, and the previous iteration did
            //not stop at the position directly before the start of the current iteration, add
            //the intermediary chracters
            else if (last != -1 && last + 1 != index[i].start)
            {
                results += word.Substring(last + 1,index[i].start - (last + 1));
            }

            //add the space before the "index" match, the actual match, and then the formatted "index"
            results += " " + word.Substring(index[i].start,(index[i].end - index[i].start) + 1)
                + "[" + index[i].value + "]";
            //remember the position of the ending for the next iteration
            last = index[i].end;
        }

        //if the last "index" did not stop at the end of the input string, add the remaining characters
        if (index[index.Keys.Count - 1].end + 1 < word.Length)
        {
            results += word.Substring(index[index.Keys.Count-1].end + 1);
        }
        //trimming spaces that may be left behind
        results = results.Trim();

        Console.WriteLine("INPUT  - " + myString);
        Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT - " + results);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

`input  - 子で子にならぬ時鳥,0:こ;2:こ;7-8:ほととぎす`

`output - 子[こ]で 子[こ]にならぬ 時鳥[ほととぎす]`

Note that this should also work with characters the English alphabet if you wanted to use English instead-

`input  - iliketocodeverymuch,2:A;4-6:B;9-12:CDEFG`

`output - il i[A]k eto[B]co deve[CDEFG]rymuch`

Comment: Hello iliketocode ! I understand most of the code, only the `for` part is a bit cryptic to me, would you mind elaborating more in details what it does ? I'm trying to figure it out through the debugger but would appreciate some hints !

Comment: @Coloris I just added some comments throughout those parts of the code.  Let me know if you still have questions on any of it.  I am not sure how you are using this code, but if there is any chance the input strings would have incorrect formatting you would first want to do some error checking to make sure the formatting is correct; then you could plug the correctly formatted strings into the mechanism I wrote to get the final results.